# Short exact sequence over non-Noetherian ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\Bbbk$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and let $A$ be a $\Bbbk$-algebra (potentially non-Noetherian).  Suppose that $M,N,P$ are finitely-generated projective $A$-modules, and we have a sequence of maps
$$
M\to N\to P
$$
such that the composition $M\to P$ is zero, and for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\operatorname{Spec}A$, the induced sequence
$$
M_{\mathfrak{p}}\to N_{\mathfrak{p}}\to P_{\mathfrak{p}}
$$
is a short exact sequence.

My question is, can we conclude that the original sequence is a short exact sequence?

I know this result holds when $A$ is Noetherian, but the proof I know works by trivializing the modules locally (viewed them as vector bundles), and in the Noetherian case it's not clear to me if that's possible.

Comment: In fact, something like this holds in great generality. Cf. [Stacks 00HN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HN).

Comment: Wow sick I'm just so out of touch with things that are non-Noetherian I forgot what holds in general.  Thank you!!

Comment: @Rafi that looks like an answer to me.